Is there a way to check if a specific user id exists within the server? without using cache || discord js
Is there a way to check if a specific user id exists within the server? without using cache
I couldn't find a working code, whether or not the user had never chatted
commands.add('test3', (arg) =>{
    
var exists = bot.users.cache.has(arg);
    
    if (exists == true) { msg.channel.send('1'); }else { msg.channel.send('2');} //msg.sme{e
}); 

This is a temporary command for testing. When user send a command with @anyuser, the bot needs to make sure the user is on the server first (otherwise it could be crashed) but nothing I tried worked properly...
Is there a better way than this?

Try to fetch the member through the guild member manager. An error will be thrown if the member does not exist. Use a try/catch block to handle the possible error.
async function exists(guild, arg) {
   try {
      const member = await guild.members.fetch(arg);
      return !!member;
   } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
      return false;
   }
}


You can use guild.members.fetch(userID) to fetch a member from the server by their user ID. If the user exists, it will return the member otherwise, it will throw an error.

  commands.add('test3', async (arg) => {
        try {
            const member = await msg.guild.members.fetch(arg);
            
           msg.channel.send(`User ID found: ${member.id}`);
           
        } catch (error) {
        
             msg.channel.send('User not found on the server.');
        }
    });


So this should be work thank you but I have another problem... Any command with async will cause this error. DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message I posted this as a different question...

Ok now I fixed the empty message problem but, now it only returns User ID found: undefined

do console.log(member); , check if there is a valid response.
